# Array of structs in C that are passed into a function

Tags: c, arrays, struct, io

I am trying to make a small program that takes in input from a file that is delimited (by "|")
for example one line in the file looks like this:

```
name|phone|address|city|state|zip
```

For some reason everytime I try to get it to write everything that is in the array of structures to a binary file the linking of the array goes wrong. I have been looking at this for a few hours and cannot figure out why it does this. One of the problems I have noticed is if I decide to run the program and I print out what is in index 0 of the array after writing something to index 1 it messes up index 0 (each index holds a struct). I am not sure why.

Please help, I have been banging my head on the keyboard for hours trying to figure out why it gives me this problem. Sorry, forgot to mention that it should be run with the first parameter being the path to the file ex
./ExerciseOne.out /path/to/file.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * ExerciseOne.c
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 24, 2012
 *      Author: kevin
 */

typedef struct personal_Info {
    char *Name;
    char *Phone;
    char *address;
    char *city;
    char *state;
    int zip;

} PInfo ;

void loopTokens(PInfo *, char *);
void PrintStruct(PInfo *);
void PrintStructArray(PInfo p[], int);
void transferText(PInfo *, int);
void transferTextBin(PInfo p[], int);
void readTextBin(FILE *, PInfo *, int );

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int index = 0;
    int numLines = 0;
    char *lineOfText = malloc(80);
    //Open File
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
    printf("File could not be opened");
    }
    else {
        fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");//inputs the argv as the vile to read
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d \n", &numLines);


    //Create Arrays for Binary and Text structs
    PInfo TextInfo[numLines];
    PInfo *TextInfo_ptr;



/*Commented code
 * TextInfo[index] = *TextInfo_ptr;//Point to structure ##Unneeded##
 *  printf("this is before the transferTextBin %s \n", TextInfo[0].Phone);//Works
 */
    while(!feof(fp)&&index<numLines){
      TextInfo_ptr = &TextInfo[index];//Structure points to the proper hole in array; current index//Looks like it advances the count for the ptr
      fgets(lineOfText, 80, fp);
      loopTokens(TextInfo_ptr,  lineOfText);//puts pointer to the array index into function
      printf("this is before the transferTextBin %s \n", TextInfo_ptr->Phone);//Works
      printf("this is before the transferTextBin %s \n", TextInfo[0].Phone);//problem second time around
      printf("this is before the transferTextBin %s \n", TextInfo[1].Phone);//works
      //PrintStruct(TextInfo_ptr);
      index++;
    }


    //transferText(TextInfo, numLines);//Will do it in regular

    printf("this is before the transferTextBin %s \n", TextInfo[0].Phone);//Here it is suddenly losing it
    transferTextBin(TextInfo, numLines);//will do it in bin

    fclose(fp);
    FILE *fBIN;
    fBIN = fopen("fOUT.dat", "rb");// may need to insert this into method
    //readTextBin(fBIN, BinInfo, numLines);
    return(0);
}


void loopTokens(PInfo *p, char *textLine){//Want to pass in INDIVDUAL structs
    char *buffer;
    int index = 0;

  p->Name = malloc(80);
  p->Phone = malloc(80);
  p->address = malloc(80);
  p->city = malloc(80);
  p->state = malloc(80);
  p->zip = 0;

        /* mallocate each field in the current structure */

    buffer = strtok(textLine, "|"); /* Tokenize the string */

    while(buffer != NULL && strcmp(textLine,"\n")){ /* loop through all tokens */
            if(index == 0){
            //strcpy(p->Name,textLine);
            p->Name = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
            else if(index == 1){
            p->Phone = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
            else if(index == 2){
            p->address = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
            else if(index == 3){
            p->city = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
            else if(index == 4){
            p->state = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
            else if(index == 5){
                p->zip = 0;
            p->zip = (int)atoi(buffer);
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
  }
  index = 0;

}

    void PrintStruct(PInfo *p){//Gets pointer to the struct
        printf("This is the supposed name: %s The Phone is : %s, the address is : %s %s %s %d\n", p->Name, p->Phone, p->address, p->city, p->state, p->zip );
    }
    void PrintStructArray(PInfo p[], int lines){//Gets Entire array of structs; prints everything out
  int index = 0;
    while(index < lines){
      printf("This is the supposed name: %s The Phone is : %s, the address is : %s %s %s %d\n", p[index].Name, p[index].Phone, p[index].address, p[index].city, p[index].state, p[index].zip );
    }
  }
void transferText(PInfo *p, int numLines){//Transfers text
  FILE *fOUT;//open file for writing
  int index = 0;
        fOUT = fopen("fOUT.txt", "w");//Open file for writing

        while(index < numLines){
          fputs(p->Name,fOUT);
          fputs(p->Phone,fOUT);
          fputs(p->address,fOUT);
          fputs(p->city,fOUT);
          fputs(p->state,fOUT);
          fputs(p->zip,fOUT);
        }

        fclose(fOUT);

    }
void transferTextBin(PInfo p[], int numLines){
    FILE *fOUT;//open file for writing
    //int index = 0;
    fOUT = fopen("fOUT.dat", "wb");
    printf("this is the phone of the first index %s", p[0].Phone );
    //printf("Ti the supposed name: %s The Phone is : %s, the address is : %s %s %s %d\n", p[index].Name, p[index].Phone, p[index].address, p[index].city, p[index].state, p[index].zip );
    //while(index < numLines){
/*  fwrite(p[index]->Name, sizeof(p[index]->Name), 1, fOUT);
    fwrite(p[index]->Phone, sizeof(p[index]->Phone), 1, fOUT);
    fwrite(p[index]->address, sizeof(p[index]->address), 1, fOUT);
    fwrite(p[index]->city, sizeof(p[index]->city), 1, fOUT);
    fwrite(p[index]->state, sizeof(p[index]->state), 1, fOUT);*/
    //fwrite(p->zip, sizeof(p->zip), 1, fOUT);
//  }
    fclose(fOUT);
    }







void readTextBin(FILE *fIN, PInfo *bInfo, int numLines){
    int index = 0;
    //char *buffer;
    printf("This is what is in the File: ");
    //bInfo[index].Name = fread(buffer, 80, 1, fIN);
    //bInfo[0]->Name = malloc(80);
    while(!feof(fIN) && index<numLines){
        fread(bInfo[index].Name, 80, 1, fIN);
        fread(bInfo[index].Phone, 80, 1, fIN);
        fread(bInfo[index].address, 80, 1, fIN);
        fread(bInfo[index].city, 80, 1, fIN);
        fread(bInfo[index].state, 80, 1, fIN);
        //fread(bInfo[index]->zip, 80, 1, fIN);
        PrintStruct(bInfo);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR... Please read http://sscce.org/

Comment: 1) your usage of `feof()` is wrong 2) the `transferText()` function will loop forever. 3) learn to use for(;;) loops. 4) learn how to use switch(){} constructs.

Comment: I am really more interested in the way I am messing up the structs in the array, I don't seem to understand why when I edit the fields in the array it messes up when i call it by the TextInfo[] notation, but thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `loopTokens`, you ought to `strcpy` the values from the `textLine` buffer to the `char*` members. You `malloc` memory for name, address etc.,

```
void loopTokens(PInfo *p, char *textLine){
    char *buffer;
    int index = 0;

    p->Name = malloc(80);
    /* snip */
    buffer = strtok(textLine, "|"); /* Tokenize the string */

    while(buffer != NULL && strcmp(textLine,"\n")){ /* loop through all tokens */
            if(index == 0){
            //strcpy(p->Name,textLine);
            p->Name = buffer;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, "|");
            index++;
            }
```

but when you assign e.g. `p->Name = buffer;`, you lose the reference to the `malloc`ed memory (bad), and let `p->Name` point to a `char` in the array pointed to by `textLine`. `strtok` modifies the buffer it is invoked on, and returns (`NULL` or) a pointer into that buffer.

So `p->Name` and friends all point into the `textLine` buffer, whose contents changes when you read in the next line.

Instead of `p->Name = buffer;`, you should

```
strcpy(p->Name, buffer);
```

(you have allocated no less memory to `p->Name` than to `textLine`, so there's no danger of writing outside the allocated memory, provided you check whether `malloc` returned `NULL`).

Comment: Worked for me!, Thanks, have been up all night trying to fix this (I wish I would have tried your method sooner). Thanks again

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

```
void loopTokens(PInfo *p, char *textLine){
    char *tok;
    int index = 0;

    if(!strcmp(textLine,"\n")) return; /* loop-invariant moved out of the loop */

    for(tok= strtok(textLine, "|"); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, "|") ) {
        switch(index++) {
          case 0:
          p->Name = strdup(tok);
            break;
        case 1:
            p->Phone = strdup(tok);
            break;
        case 2:
            p->address = strdup(tok);
            break;
        case 3:
            p->city = strdup(tok);
            break;
        case 4:
            p->state = strdup(tok);
            break;
        case 5:
            p->zip = 0;
            p->zip = atoi(tok);
            break;
        default:
            return;
            }
     }

}
```